How can I open an app link from android browser
I have created an app link according to this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

I have created a manifest like:

     <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myhost.hu" />
     </intent-filter>


I have created a content in asset.json in my host: /.well-known/assetlinks.json

I can open the app link in android 12 or above from other app with creating an intent. Or I can open it if I scan a QR code with the url containing the app link.
What I see: chrome opens the app link as a web page
How can I open the app link from browser? For instrance: user arrives from other web page, and I would like to open my app

Do you test applinks on release build? You need different files assetlinks.json on your host for debug and release builds.

I use both: release and test build with different domain and different assetlinks.json
